# scroll the screen in android app?

Tags: android

while trying to scroll the screen in my app , here is the layout before using scrollview and linearlayout https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMCW.jpg 
and here is the strange layout I got after using scrollview and linearlayout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAL5p.jpg
and here is my current xml code    ,please help me fix this error

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Web_guide"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/google_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtube"
    android:background="@drawable/youtube"
    android:layout_below="@+id/google"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/instagram"
    android:background="@drawable/insta"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/instagram"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/iii" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_logo_bluebg_2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tumbler"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/linkedin_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/google_plus"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linked_in"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/soundcloud"
    android:background="@drawable/google_plus_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/pinterest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pinterest_alt" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/flicker"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linked_in"
    android:background="@drawable/flicker" />

<ImageButton
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:id="@+id/vine"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/vine" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/gmail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gmail" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line in **scrollview**

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"<!-- Remove line -->
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

And move this inside the linear layout.

Finally put everything (except scrollview) inside a **new Linear Layout**.
And put that new Linear Layout in **scrollview**

Answer (score 0):

To get the ScrollView to fill the screen you can add the following line to your ScrollView xml:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```